# Disabling view animation during a segue (or vice versa)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, target-action

I have a `rightBarButtonItem` that slides up a view from the bottom of the screen like a `UIActionSheet`, and everything works fine except when I press a button that pushes a `UIViewController` and the `rightBarButton` almost at the same time, the two will both execute, thus resulting in a slide-up view over a screen that is totally unrelated.

Is there a way to get some notification or something so I can stop the view from animating when a view controller is being pushed, or the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

With no code snippets its hard to understand what you are doing to cause this behavior. To me it sounds like you just need to restructure your button target actions. Why would u want to slide your button up from the bottom and push a VC at the same time if that will just hide the previously slid rightBarButton. Maybe just remove the slider code from the target action when that VC gets pushed.

There is a method you can call to stop animations your probably aware of.

```
- pushViewController:Animated:
```